# Pass Block Value to Template From View Django

Tags: django, templates, variables, view, block

I am trying to pass the values (as defined in the `view` below) for use in a  template.

**View**

```
from Scanner.forms import SubmitDomain
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.context import RequestContext
#from django.template import loader


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Page was found</h1>')

def Scan(request):
        ## Setup Template.
        return render(request, 'VA/index.html',
                     {'pagetitle': 'Home'},
                     {'container_content' : 'Testing some content dude!'},
                     ##{'form' : 'form'},   
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[]))

        form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data

        if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
            if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
                form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
                form.save()
```

**Im using the following in my template:**

```
<title>Website Name - {% block pagetitle %}{% endblock pagetitle %}</title>
{% block container_content %}{% endblock container_content %}
```

Error Im getting:

```
ender_to_string() got multiple values for keyword argument 'context_instance'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please excuse my newbieness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass them from the view:

```
def your_view(request):
    # .... your code here ....

    return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
        'form' : form,
        'page_title': 'My page',
        'meta_description': 'Some desc'
    })
```

And in your template:

```
<meta name="description" content="{{ meta_description }}">
<title>Website Name - {{ page_title }}</title>
```

However this seems not really DRY since you have to repeat it in every view and every template. So what I would do is create blocks with some default values in the base template, example `base.html`:

```
<meta name="description" content="{% block blk_metadesc %} Some default meta here {% endblock blk_metadesc %}">
<title>Website Name - {% block blk_pagetitle %}Default title{% endblock blk_pagetitle %}</title>
```

Then you can override them in your child templates *if you want*, example `child.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block blk_metadesc %} {{ meta_description }} {% endblock blk_metadesc %}
{% block blk_pagetitle %} {{ page_tile }} {% endblock blk_pagetitle %}
```

So in your child templates, you don't have to do the same stuff over and over again, but only override the default value in blocks if you want to.

**EDIT**

Your view code is very messy:

```
def Scan(request):
    ## Setup Template.
    return render(request, 'VA/index.html', # after you do 'return' in a function, the following code won't run
                 {'pagetitle': 'Home'},
                 {'container_content' : 'Testing some content dude!'}, # this line caused the error, you can pass only ONE dict as the argument.
                 ##{'form' : 'form'},   
    context_instance=RequestContext(request, processors=[])) # you don't really need this context_instance at all.

    # the following code won't run

    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
            form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
            form.save()
```

I would rewrite that view like this:

```
def Scan(request):
    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data

    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
            form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
            form.save()

    return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
        'pagetitle': 'Home',
        'container_content' : 'Testing some content dude!',
        'form' : 'form' # comment out this line if you don't need the form.
    })
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, can you look at the code I provided and tell me if Im on the right track?

Comment: Is that your `base.html` code? If so, it looks like you are on the right track. Just notice the default value in my answer, it can be useful for you someday.

Comment: Nope, I still can't see the `return` part of function `Scan()` ?!

Comment: That is the full file, do you mean the contents of the form called form = SubmitDomain ?

Comment: In regards to your current answer, where do the {% block pagetitle %} {{ page_tile }} {% endblock pagetitle %}   "{{page_title}}" come from? Where is this value set?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34403/discussion-between-hieu-nguyen-and-codetalk)

Comment: from the view, I changed the name of the blocks a bit to avoid the confusion. You can check the edited answer.